# undefined instance method for Factory Girl class when using spring prelaoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a class defined inside my Factory girl definition as follows

```
factory :user, class: User do
 trait :successful do
  after(:build) do |u|
    u.calling_method_from_external_concerns_or_mockey_pached_method
  end
end
```

and created the factor object as follows

```
@user        = build(:user,         :successful)
```

it always pass without the spring preloader, but when I run with spring, it only pass for the first time, after the first time and I make any change in the repo it raises a undefined method (calling_method_from_external_concerns_or_mockey_pached_method) when creating the factory girl object. NOTE: This happens when I make any change in my repo (adding extra line or any other changes), if I stop the preloader run again it would pass.

inside the after build block

```
 after(:build) do |u|
    u.methods.include?(:calling_method_from_external_concerns_or_mockey_pached_method)
    # returns false

    User.new.include?(:calling_method_from_external_concerns_or_mockey_pached_method)
    # returns true
 end
```

The undefined method is defined inside a module which is included before the test

```
  module Mock
   def calling_method_from_external_concerns_or_mockey_pached_method; end
  end
```

Also tried monkey patch as follows inside a different class file, I get the same pattern as mentioned before

```
  class User
     def calling_method_from_external_concerns_or_mockey_pached_method; end
  end
```